# How do I make it such that a TCP connection will timeout if the connection doesn't receive a response every second?

Tags: go, networking, tcp

I'm trying to create a TCP server that will timeout if the client does not respond within the span of every second.

I tried:

```
func main() {
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:8000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for {
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        conn.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(timeout))
        if err != nil {
            log.Print(err)
        }
        go handleConn(conn)
    }

}
```

where the timeout is a single second but the disconnects immediately, not even waiting for a reply.

Comment: Did you read the documentation of `SetDeadline` here? https://pkg.go.dev/net#Conn

Comment: Offtop: did you think about using web sockets? 
eg. 
https://github.com/gorilla/websocket
https://echo.labstack.com/cookbook/websocket/

Comment: @HymnsForDisco I did. Don't quite get its implementation for my use case and would like some examples

Comment: From the docs “An idle timeout can be implemented by repeatedly extending the deadline after successful Read or Write calls.”. You need to do this in your `handleConn` function.

Comment: I don't see you setting a timeout, so maybe that is the problem? I mean the variable timeout. Try replacing the timeout with time.Second

Comment: @IamSoClueless. Already set it. The variable is set to a single second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want can be achieved by setting socket options on your listener. Tweak the values as per your needs

> Note that this is its own KeepAlive and does not depend on incoming/outgoing data by application

```
func enableTCPKeepAlive(listener *net.TCPListener) error {
    rawConn, err := listener.SyscallConn()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    cfg := config.TLSServerConfig()
    rawConn.Control(
        func(fdPtr uintptr) {
            // got socket file descriptor. Setting parameters.
            fd := int(fdPtr)
            //Idle time before sending probe.
            err = syscall.SetsockoptInt(fd, syscall.IPPROTO_TCP, syscall.TCP_KEEPIDLE, cfg.TCPKAIdleTime)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            //Number of probes.
            err := syscall.SetsockoptInt(fd, syscall.IPPROTO_TCP, syscall.TCP_KEEPCNT, cfg.TCPKANumProbes)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            //Wait time after an unsuccessful probe.
            err = syscall.SetsockoptInt(fd, syscall.IPPROTO_TCP, syscall.TCP_KEEPINTVL, cfg.TCPKAInterval)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            // go syscall doesn't have the constant 0x12 (18) for TCP_USER_TIMEOUT.
            // 0x12 value referenced from linux kernel source code header:
            // include/uapi/linux/tcp.h
            err = syscall.SetsockoptInt(fd, syscall.IPPROTO_TCP, 0x12, cfg.TCPKAUserTimeout)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        })
    return nil
}
```

There are more options available than the ones I have mentioned above.
Call this function on your listener before the for loop.

```
func main() {
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:8000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = enableTCPKeepAlive(listener)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for {
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        conn.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(timeout))
        if err != nil {
            log.Print(err)
        }
        go handleConn(conn)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is almost always in code that is not posted here. The function obviously works like a charme:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "log"
    "net"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:8000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    go func() {
        for {
            conn, err := listener.Accept()
            if err != nil {
                log.Print(err)
                return
            }
            go func(c net.Conn) {
                defer c.Close()

                conn.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(2 * time.Second))
                if err != nil {
                    log.Print(err)
                    return
                }
                buf := make([]byte, 1<<19) // 512 KB
                for {
                    _, err := conn.Read(buf)
                    if err != nil {
                        log.Print(err)
                        break
                    }
                }
            }(conn)
        }
    }()

payload := make([]byte, 1<<20)
_, err = rand.Read(payload) // generate a random payload
if err != nil {
    log.Print(err)
}

conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", listener.Addr().String())
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
log.Println("Connected to server.")

time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)

_, err = conn.Write(payload)
if err != nil {
    log.Print(err)
}

listener.Close()
}
```